# Chord and lyrics format issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'll be making a chord and lyrics website. However, the chords cannot be copied because the content is messed up. The desired goal is when the user tries to copy the chord and lyrics and paste it in MS Word or any text editor, the post content (strings, not html) must still be the same without affecting its format which is the chord is on top of the lyrics.

[image]

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/akoni/tak9mo0y/)

```js
var markUpChordLines = function() {
  jQuery('.post-content').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, '<span class="chord" data-chord="$1"></span>');
  });

  jQuery('.chord').each(function () {
    jQuery(this.nextSibling).wrapAll('<span class="lyric_content"></span>');
    jQuery(this.nextSibling).appendTo(this);
  });
};

markUpChordLines();
```

```css
span.chord {
  position       : relative;
  display        : inline-flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  vertical-align : bottom;
  }
span.chord:before {
  content     : attr(data-chord);
  position    : relative;
  font-style  : italic;
  font-weight : bold;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post-content">
  <p style="display: none;">G  D </p>
  <p>Al [G]contrario di [D]te  </p>
  <p>Io[F] non lo s[A]o</p>
  <p>[D] Se è g[G]iusto co[F]sì    </p>
  <p>C[A]omunqu[G]e [D]sia</p>
  <p>Io [G#sus]non mi mu[Fm]ovo</p>
  <p>Io r[Bm]esto qu[E]i</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You’re already generating the elements… why not just `'<span class="chord" data-chord="$1">$1</span>'` and merge the non-`content` properties in `:before` with `span.chord`? Why do you need the `data-chord` attribute?

Comment: Ohh Nice catch. I didn't notice that. Thanks. However, I did try your suggestion, but the content when doing copy/paste are messed up .

Comment: what sort of copy are you looking for ? the same as the original post-content ?

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes, sir. The same as the original post-content. Like what we view on the front-end.

Comment: It's okay, sir. I can wait.

Comment: the question is where you will do the past. HTML/CSS formatting cannot be pasted everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do that, going through html / tables. the rtf format posed too many problems and made me waste time.

```js
const txtP        = document.querySelectorAll('.post-content p')
  ,  rgxCut       = /(?=\[)|(?<=\])/
  ,  zCopyChanged = document.querySelector('#copyChangedZone')
  ;
txtP.forEach(pLine=>pLine.innerHTML = setParagraph_Chord( pLine.textContent ))
  
zCopyChanged.addEventListener('copy', evt => 
  {
  let lines =  (''+document.getSelection()).split('\n').filter(Boolean)

  let tPlain = lines.join('\n')
    , t_html = lines.reduce((a,c)=>a+setTable_chord(c),'')

  evt.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', tPlain )
  evt.clipboardData.setData('text/html', t_html )

  evt.preventDefault()
  })

function setParagraph_Chord (line)
  {
  let newP = line
            .replaceAll('] [',']&emsp;[')
            .split(rgxCut)
            .map(el=>
          {
          if (el[0]!=='[') return el
          let chord = el.substring(1,el.length-1)
          return `<span class="chord" data-chord="${chord}">${el}</span>`
          })
  return  newP.join('')
  }
function setTable_chord( line )
  {
  let tc = []
    , tl = []
    , tx = true
    ;
  line.split(rgxCut).forEach(el=>
    {
    if (el[0]!=='[') 
      {
      if (tx) tc.push('');
      tl.push(el)   
      tx = true     
      }
    else
      {
      tc.push(el.substring(1,el.length-1))
      tx = false
      }
    })
  let rep = '<table style="border-collapse:collapse;white-space:pre;"><tboby>'
          + '<tr><td style="padding:0;font:12px;border:none"><b><i>'
          + tc.join('</td><td style="padding:0;font:12px;border:none"><b><i>')
          + '</td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0;font:15px;border:none">'
          + tl.join('</td><td style="padding:0;font:15px;border:none">')
          + '</td></tr></tboby></table><br>'
  return rep
  }
```

```css
.post-content {
  line-height : 20px;
  font-size   : 16px;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin      : 2em .7em;
  }
span.chord {
  font-size : 0; 
  position  : relative;
  background: #ca7a6c;
  }
span.chord:after {
  position    : absolute;
  font-size   : 12px;
  top         :  -32px;
  content     : attr(data-chord);
  font-style  : italic;
  font-weight : bold;
  color       : blue;
  transform   : rotate( -30deg );  
  }
p {
  margin : .7em;
  }
h3 { margin-bottom:0; } 
h5 { margin:0 .8em; }
```

```html
<h3> test a copy here <small>(on lyrics) </small>and past it to :</h3>
<h5> 1 - a simple text editor ( kEdit, notePad...)</h5>
<h5> 2 - a writter editor ( LibreOffice Writer, Word...)</h5>
<hr>
<div id="copyChangedZone">
  <div class="post-content">
    <p>Al [G]contrario di [D]te</p>
    <p>Io[F] non lo s[A]o</p>
    <p>[D] Se è g[G]iusto co[F]sì</p>
    <p>C[A]omunqu[G]e [D]sia</p>
    <p>Io [G#sus]non mi mu[Fm]ovo</p>
    <p>Io r[Bm]esto qu[E]i</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <p>There were [C]bells on a [G°]hill</p>
    <p>[G°]But I [Dm]never heard them [Fm]ringing</p>
    <p>No, I [C]never [Em]heard them [E♭m]at [Dm]all</p>
    <p>[G7]Till there was [C]you [Dm] [G7]</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <p>There were [C]birds in the [G°]sky</p>
    <p>But I [Dm]never saw them [Fm]winging</p>
    <p>No, I [C]never [Em]saw them [E♭m]at [Dm]all</p>
    <p>[G7]Till there was [C]you [F] [C]</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <p>Then there was [F]music and [Fm]wonderful [C]roses</p>
    <p>They [A7]tell me</p>
    <p>In [Dm]sweet fragrant [D7]meadows</p>
    <p>Of [G7]dawn and [G+]dew</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion sir. I updated my question

Comment: Actually sir, my goal is just simple. It's just my poor choice of words made my question very complicated.

Comment: No, sir. I think we really have a misunderstanding. What I meant is when we copy the lyrics and chords of the website (ultimateguitar or  internetchorddatabase) and paste to any text editor, the chords are on top of the lyrics. My current output using my code hides the chords, only the lyrics are visible. My goal is just like the same as ultimateguitar and  internetchorddatabase.com.

Comment: It's fine sir as long as the chords are on top of the lyrics. I understand the copied text or spacing may differ compared to what the user viewed the content of the website.

Comment: I'm also in a country where "maam/sir" shows a sign of respect to all kinds of people whether poor or rich. Such titles is not about feeling superior or inferior, or perpetuating the hierarchy – it is simply a matter of showing respect. https://amp.rappler.com/move-ph/balikbayan/identity/102537-netizen-reactions-maam-sir-philippines

I will stop calling you sir as a respect in your culture too.

Comment: WOW!!! Really amazing! Can't thank you enough. I truly appreciate your hardwork

Comment: I really wonder how you did that. I have the idea but I don't know how to code like that. Totally out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I have done that:

```js
const txtP  = document.querySelectorAll('.post-content p')
  ,  rgxCut = /(?=\[)|(?<=\])/
  ;
txtP.forEach(pLine=>
  {
  let newP =
    pLine.textContent.split(rgxCut)
        .map(el=>
          {
          if (el[0]!=='[') return el
          let chord = el.substring(1,el.length-1)
          return `<span class="chord" data-chord="${chord}">${el}</span>`
          })
  pLine.innerHTML = newP.join('')
  })
```

```css
.post-content {
  line-height : 20px;
  font-size   : 16px;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin      : 2em .7em;
  }
span.chord {
  font-size : 0; 
  position  : relative;
  }
span.chord:after {
  position    : absolute;
  font-size   : 12px;
  top         :  -30px;
  content     : attr(data-chord);
  font-style  : italic;
  font-weight : bold;
  color       : blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-content">
  <p style="display: none;">G  D </p>
  <p>Al [G]contrario di [D]te</p>
  <p>Io[F] non lo s[A]o</p>
  <p>[D] Se è g[G]iusto co[F]sì</p>
  <p>C[A]omunqu[G]e [D]sia</p>
  <p>Io [G#sus]non mi mu[Fm]ovo</p>
  <p>Io r[Bm]esto qu[E]i</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not not what I want sir. I meant the view itself where the chord is on top of the lyrics. Thanks for your effort sir. Really appreciate it

Comment: @enrique did you try the copy commend on? And where would you like to see the chords placed? I looked on google image the different display possibilities, you do not indicate any preference ...

Comment: Oh my apologies sir. Here's a good reference. 
https://www.internetchorddatabase.com/Songs/Till_There_Was_You_by_Beatles_The_v1#

When I try to copy the chords and lyrics in that website to Notepad or Word, all content still intact.

Comment: Or can be https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/foo-fighters/learn-to-fly-chords-1846395

Comment: I did try to copy the code you've suggested. However, it's not what I meant on my question. But I found it great sir maybe I could find it useful later on this project